# Drupal 7 conditionally check a field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-fields

I'm trying to write a conditional statement in a template file to check if the value of a 'node reference' field *is not equal* to a certain value. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$value = ( $content['field_collection_or_bespoke']['#items']['0']['value'] );

if ( $value != 'bespoke' ) : ?>

    // Do something if not bespoke 

<?php endif ?>
```

At the moment it is always evaluating to true. I'm not sure if `$value` is not getting the correct field or that the value I'm testing against is wrong. If that's the case how can I find the values of the `field_collection_or_bespoke` field?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is probably in the incorrect reference:

```
$value = ( $content['field_collection_or_bespoke']['#items']['0']['value'] );
```

Language key is missing in the array.

It should be something like:

```
$value = ( $content['field_collection_or_bespoke']['und']['0']['value'] );
```

Please do `Print_r($content['field_collection_or_bespoke']);` to get details.

Answer (score 1):

If Its a Theme file or function try print the variable passed the theme file or function

using *replace $var with your variable name.always use strcmp() for comparing string values

```
echo "<pre>"
print($var);
die;
```